# Select method to execute inside thread before starting thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I created a small flask app to download images and text from pages, this can take verly long time, so
I would like to execute my requests in parell. I create threaded tasks. I would like this tasks to be able to download text or images from sites. I keep my tasks in a list of workers. 
However I would like to select a method which thread will execute and then start whole thread.
How can I pass my method to thread run method()? Will this be a sub daemon thread?

```py
import threading
import time

workers = []

class SavePage:
    def get_text(self):
        print("Getting text")

    def get_images(self):
        print("Getting images")


class Task(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_page = SavePage()

    def get_text_from_page(self):
        self.save_page.get_text()

    def get_images_from_page(self):
        self.save_page.get_images()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task = Task()

    task.get_images_from_page()  # Why this executes, when I didn't put task.start() ?
    # Moreover, is this really threaded? or just uses a method from class Task?

    workers.append(task)  # I want this list to be empty, after job is finished
    print("".join(str(worker.is_alive()) for worker in workers))  #
    print(workers)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> task.get_images_from_page()  # Why this executes, when I didn't put task.start() ?
> # Moreover, is this really threaded? or just uses a method from class Task?
> ```

It's not threaded. It's just a normal method call in the main thread.

`Thread.start` is the method that will start `Thread.run` function inside another thread.

You could set some state in `__init__` to choose which function to execute:

```
class Task(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, action):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_page = SavePage()
        self.action = action

    def get_text_from_page(self):
        self.save_page.get_text()

    def get_images_from_page(self):
        self.save_page.get_images()

    def run(self):
        if self.action == "text":
            self.get_text_from_page()
        elif self.action == "images":
            self.get_images_from_page()
```

Keep in mind that threads can be run in simpler way by passing target function:

```
def target_func():
    save_page = SavePage()
    save_page.get_images()

t = threading.Thread(target=target_func)
t.start()

# or in this simple case:

save_page = SavePage()

t = threading.Thread(target=save_page.get_images)
t.start()
```

Comment: Yes, that was helpfull, can you tell me also, why I am getting stopped daemons, 
when the job is finished? I never specified instructions like 
d = threading.Thread(name='daemon', target=d)
d.setDaemon(True) 

What I get:
[<Task(Task, stopped daemon 4192)>]

Comment: Yes. It means that the job is finished.